A counter example for narrowing reference conversion rules in Java
Consider the rules of allowed narrowing reference conversion mentioned in the JLS section 1.5.6.1.
The following is an example of a narrowing reference conversion:
ArrayList<? extends Integer> l = getList(); // Assume getList() is defined
ArrayList<Number> ll = (ArrayList<Number>) l;

The code above is rejected by javac and by eclipse JDT. My issue is that, as far as I can tell, it satisifies all the necessary constraints listed in the JLS in order for it to be an allowed narrowing reference conversion. And so, I want to know if this is a bug in the compiler, JLS or I am misunderstanding something.
Here is a walk through of every rule applied to the example. First we have the source type  S := ArrayList<? extends Integer> and the target type T := ArrayList<Number>. For a narrowing reference conversion to be allowed, the JLS lists three constraints, I am going to swap the second and third for convenience:
1. S is not a subtype of T (§4.10) -> It is clearly the case that ArrayList<? extends Integer> is not a subtype of List<Number>
3. S is a class or interface type, and T is a class or interface type, and S names a class or interface that is not disjoint from the class or interface named by T. -> S and T name the same classe ArrayList thus they are not disjoint.
2. If there exists a parameterized type X that is a supertype of T, and a parameterized type Y that is a supertype of S, such that the erasures of X and Y are the same, then X and Y are not provably distinct (§4.5). -> S and T are parametrizations of the same type ArrayList, so the question is, are ArrayList<? extends Integer> and ArrayList<Number> provably distinct?. Let's see:

Two parameterized types are provably distinct if either of the following is true:
(i) They are parameterizations of distinct generic type declarations.
(ii) Any of their type arguments are provably distinct.

The two types are indeed parametrizations of the same generic type ArrayList. So the question becomes, are the type arguments ? extends Integer and Number provably distinct? Here is the rule:

Two type arguments are provably distinct if one of the following is true: (i) (not relevant). (ii) One type argument is a type variable or wildcard, with a bound (if a type variable) or an upper bound (if a wildcard, using capture conversion (§5.1.10), if necessary) of S; and the other type argument T is not a type variable or wildcard; and neither |S| <: |T| nor |T| <: |S| (§4.8, §4.10). Or (iii) (not relevant).

As you can see, the second rule applies as we have a ? extends Integer as the first type and the second type Number which is neither a type variable nor a wildcard. The wildcard in the first type is upper-bounded by Integer which is a subtype of Number. Hence according to this rule, The two type arguments are not provably distinct. And by that all the listed constraints for allowed narrowing reference conversion are satisfied. That is if I didn't miscalculate something .
Below is the complete example that you can copy-past to test:
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<? extends Integer> l = getList();
        ArrayList<Number> ll = (ArrayList<Number>) l;
    }

    static ArrayList<? extends Integer> getList() { return null; }
}

Strangely, if we swap the upper-bound in S (Integer) and the type T (Number) as indicated below, the compiler does not reject it:
 ArrayList<? extends Number> l = getList();
 ArrayList<Integer> ll = (ArrayList<Integer>) l;

If anything, the first example makes more sense than this one. But yet this one pass and the first does not.
There is a chance that I misinterpreted the JLS rules, but if I am not, I think this would be a bug in the compiler. What are your thoughts on this.
